# Reset windows phone 8 wallet pin

Tags: 8.0, wallet

So it looks like windows store and wallet have a pin.  It seems that they forgot to give you a method to reset this pin.  Is there a way to reset it?  I can't find anything on the Microsoft account pages.  And there seems to be no info mentioning a reset on the [wallet FAQ](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/basics/wallet-faq)

Comment: Microsoft brilliantly decided that the only way to solve this is to do a full reset on the phone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft brilliantly decided that the only way to solve this is to do a full reset on the phone.  Make sure you manually sync before doing this if you've made changes recently.  The re-sync process wasn't too bad, except that it takes a couple hours and then there are some system settings and other things like apps not remembering your account info.  So it takes a while to fully 'restore' your phone.

please consider voting for the fix!
https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/6010265-wallet-pin-reset-without-factory-reboot-when-walle#comments

Comment: I think the full reset is perfect reasonable since you can store all your credit card data. Imagine if you have a simple "tap here to reset the pin". Every people know you phone pin can do this.

Comment: They could make the tap to reset just clear all that data.  I'd rather have to reenter just the credit data vs resetting the whole phone.  The worst is the Lumia phones because you then have to re-download huge map packs if you only downloaded a few states.

Comment: Also it would be nice if one can find this info on MS pages...

Comment: @VitorCanova, obviously "click here to get all the credit card info" would be stupid.  But "click here to wipe out your wallet only" (instead of your entire phone) would be a lot more intelligent.

Comment: So wiping your credit card info should wipe out the credit card details linked to your Microsoft account? I don't think its reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

You can see your Wallet pin from a computer that your logged on to with the same Microsoft Account: Go to Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Credential Manager, and chose Web Credentials. (this is how it works for me on Windows 10, if the version of Windows that your using doesn't follow this path, just type "Credential Manager" into the search on "Start"). Then scroll down to WalletPin and expand it (click the arrow next to it), then click "Show", you'll have to put your Microsoft Account password in. It should show you your Wallet Pin.